# reactJS copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wonder if something like this is doable in reactjs (i'm new).
In this example, when user hovers over the email address (at the bottom), it says: copy to clipboard, once clicked, email is copied.

https://shapefarm.net/contact/

I have the styling, once hovered, the text appears, but I really don't know how to implement the functionality, any ideas? Thank you!

```
    const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <>
        <FooterContainer>
            <FooterBg>
        
              <div className="footer-wrapper">
                <div className="info">
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  <div className="hovertext-container">
                    <p className="hovertext-p1">
                      mymail@test.com
                    </p>
                    <p className="hovertext-p2">copy to clipboard</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  
                </div>
                <div>
                  <SocialMedia />
                </div>
                
              </div>
            </FooterBg>
        </FooterContainer>
    </>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

Comment: you can find your answer in the following question, good luck
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
onClick={() => {navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.state.textToCopy)}}
```

is going to do the job, you can also try out [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-copy-to-clipboard) npm package.

Answer (score -1):

```js
    const Footer = () => {
let email = "mymail@test.com";
  return (
    <>
        <FooterContainer>
            <FooterBg>
        
              <div className="footer-wrapper">
                <div className="info">
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  <div className="hovertext-container">
                    <p className="hovertext-p1">
                      mymail@test.com
                    </p>
                    <p onClick={async () => {
                await navigator.clipboard.writeText(email)
                alert("Copied text!")
                }}
                    className="hovertext-p2">copy to clipboard</p>
                  </div>
                  
                  
                </div>
                <div>
                  <SocialMedia />
                </div>
                
              </div>
            </FooterBg>
        </FooterContainer>
    </>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

Answer (score -1):

This component allows users to easily copy an invitation link with a single click, making it super convenient for sharing referral links or any other important information. The button updates its state dynamically to let users know when the content has been successfully copied.

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
    const YourReactComponent = () => {
      const [invitationCode] = useState('ref_id=5003');
      const [copyText, setCopyText] = useState('Copy to invite');
    
      const copyCode = async () => {
        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(invitationCode);
        setCopyText('Copied');
      };
    
      const reset = () => {
        setCopyText('Copy to invite');
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{`Your Translation Function for IbLink`}</p>
          <p className="copy-link text-truncate">
            ref_id=5003
          </p>
          <span onClick={copyCode} onMouseOut={reset} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
            <button className="ma-0 ml-2 text-capitalize btn-account" onClick={copyCode}>
              <i className="anticon anticon-copy" style={{ marginRight: '4px' }}></i>
              <b>{`Your Translation Function for copy`}</b>
            </button>
          </span>
          <span>{copyText}</span>
        </div>
      );
    };
   export default YourReactComponent;
```

Feel free to tailor the description based on your specific context and any additional details you'd like to emphasize.